# FreeCommander shows extensions always in lowercase

Tags: freecommander

In FreeCommander extensions are always lower case.
How can I avoid this? I tried in "Settings", but did not find any related option.

### Update

Even on Windows, some applications, not necessarily under our control, are case sensitive. 
To prevent them to fail, one has to check the names and possibly rename files. Now I do this outside FreeCommander (with cmd.exe), it would be nice and less time consuming to do it inside FreeCommander; also I don't see what the actual use of changing the original case is.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: There is some software which depends from case, e.g. R scripts should be upper case and therefore you need to use windows Explorer to check this.

Comment: Then the script should convert the extension to uppercase, not FreeCommander.

Comment: yes, but, despite the script extension is ".R", FreeCommander shows it as ".r"

Comment: So when the script pulls the extension from FreeCommander, convert it to uppercase, THEN have the script proceed.